# How can I convert MIDI files to WAV using the Windows sound font?

Tags: midi

I am interested in converting some old MIDI files to WAV using the default Windows MIDI soundfont (for nostalgic reasons), located at `C:\windows\system32\drivers\gm.dls`.

I am aware I can simply play the MIDI's on Windows Media Player and then record the computer's stereo mix as one method but I'd like something a little cleaner, especially as WMP seems to be somewhat laggy these days. What software can I use to accomplish this?